# Probability of communcation wires

Tags: probability

A communication network between three locations X Y and Z. There are links
between each location and each link has a probability of failing:

$XY = 0.1$

$YZ = 0.2$

$XZ = 0.5$

F is the event that X can send a message to Z, either directly (XZ), or through links XY and YZ.

What would be the sample space S consisting of 3-tuples representing the three links XY,YZ,XZ? If a
link is working, assign it the value 1 and assign it 0 if the link is failing. 
List all outcomes in S.

List all outcomes in F

Find P(F) (probability of F).

Im not even sure how to do the sample space in this question...

Answer (score 1):

As it says, the sample space is a set of $3-$tuples.  Each element represents whether one of the links is working.  You need to define which element corresponds to which of the three links.  How many $3-$tuples are there with elements from $\{0,1\}?$  What is $E?$  It hasn't been mentioned before.

Comment: correction* F is what i meant to say

Comment: Have you figured out the sample space?  Then for each event, you need to figure out whether $F$ is true, whether $X$ and $Z$ are connected.

Comment: Would the sample space be: XY,YZ, and XZ alone?

Comment: No, the sample space assigns a value of $0$ or $1$ to each of those variables, indicating whether that link is working or not.  So $ (0,1,1)$ encodes the fact that XY is broken but YZ and XZ are working.  There are $2^3$ possibilities.  The possibilities have different probabilities because each link has a different probability to work.  You are supposed to figure out the probability of each element in the sample space that causes F to be true and add them up to get the overall probability

Comment: why would you say 2^3

Comment: Because you have three binary choices.  Each of the three links can be working or not.  Then you use the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)

Comment: (1,1,1)(0,0,0)(1,0,0)(1,1,0)(0,0,1)(0,1,1)(0,1,0)(1,0,1) Have I got them all?

Comment: Yes. Now which of those make the link work?

Comment: Well I got (1,1,1) (since all work), (1,1,0) (XY-->YZ), (0,0,1) (XZ directly), (0,1,1) (XZ direct), (1,0,1) (XZ direct)... I believe they are the ones?

Comment: when it says "

List all outcomes in F", what does it mean

Comment: That is just what you have done

Comment: Now you need the probability of each one